# Files are not deleted when trying to use file.delete()

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I am trying to delete all files from my directory(without deleting the directory itself) and I looked around on stackoverflow, none of the solutions I found did work neither did my own code. It seemed to delete some files but for others it didn't and I don't understand why. The files dewi1, dewi2, dewi3 etc. are all copies of each other but renamed, when running this code none of these files were open or in use.

```
    File directory = new File("C:/Users/TUDelftSID/Downloads/Primal-PvM/Primal-PvM/pox/data/logs/Packetlogs");
    File[] allFilesInDir = directory.listFiles();

    for (int K = 0; K < allFilesInDir.length; K++) {
        if (allFilesInDir[K].delete()) {
            System.out.println("Succesfully Deleted: " + allFilesInDir[K] + " !");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to delete " + allFilesInDir[K] + " !");
        }
    }
```

This is What I used, as far as I can tell, the files should all be deleted; however this is the result. [image]

Why is this going on?

I already tried this aswell:

```
for(File file: directory.listFiles()) 
if (!file.isDirectory()) 
    file.delete();
```

And this one:

```
Arrays.stream(directory).listFiles()).forEach(File::delete);
```

Both did not work :/, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Gerben - I don't see any issue with your code.

JavaDoc recommends this -

public boolean delete()
Deletes the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname. If this pathname denotes a directory, then the directory must be empty in order to be deleted.
Note that the Files class defines the delete method to throw an IOException when a file cannot be deleted. This is useful for error reporting and to diagnose why a file cannot be deleted.

Try to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html
and see whether you are getting any IOException.